# Get gps metadata from image in dropbox using PHP

Tags: php, metadata, dropbox-api

I am trying to get specific metadata of an image located in dropbox using PHP and the Dropbox API.
After I connect to dropbox and list the images, I do this:

```
 $md = $dbxClient->getMetadata($path);
 print_r ($md);
```

Where the $path is the directory to my image. This works perfectly but I need to get more metadata regarding GPS location. In the Dropbox API (general view for Python, PHP, Java etc.) it says I have to set "include_media_info" to true to get gps metadata. 
Going to the PHP part it has the function GetMetaData() with only one parameter: string
($path The Dropbox path to a file or folder). 
Is there a way to get detailed metadata using the Dropbox API for PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the PHP library doesn't support the `include_media_info` parameter, so you'd need to modify the source code of the library to add support.

E.g. you could add this method:

```
function getMetadataWithMediaInfo($path)
{
    Path::checkArg("path", $path);
    return $this->_getMetadata($path, array("include_media_info" => "true"));
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's *include_media_info*, i read the docs and it looks like *list* to me

Comment: Yes. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata. The `list` parameter controls whether a listing of folder contents are returned when you call metadata on a folder. `include_media_info` controls whether a `photo_info`/`video_info` dictionary is returned in the response.

Comment: Hmmm. Adding this function in my client.php file and executing it in my script didn't seem to work either.

Comment: It worked. I had two different dropbox folders and modified the wrong one. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the source, try this:

```
$md = $dbxClient->_getMetadata($path,array("list" => "true"));
```

or edit the core `getMetadata` and change its hard coded parameter **list** to true

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The line you suggest doesn't work. It return an error cause of the _ in get Metadata. Do you have any idea in which folder is the getMetada method?

Comment: Hmmm. I found the folder and I changed the list to true. But it doesn't give me a different result. I know this image has gps related metadata but the array with the metadata doesn't return anything! Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps dropbox strips the data  under certain circumstances?